# Limit of the scroll area on google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

How can I set bounds for the scroll area on google maps?

Create `MapView` subclass and override `computeScroll()`?  Or maybe other options?

Answer (score -1):

I'd set a listener for the [`moveend` event](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMap2.moveend). In that listener, I'd examine the bounds of the map using the [`getBounds()` method](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMap2.getBounds), and figure out if the bounds are acceptable, or if not, where the new centre of the map needs to be. Then I'd call the [`panTo()` method](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMap2.panTo) to move the map to where the bounds will be acceptable.

This lets scrolling happen, then corrects it. If you want to prevent the scrolling from going too far, then try listening for other move events before `moveend`.

This is for version 2 of the GMaps API, which is deprecated. Use similar techniques on the [version 3 API, especially the Map class](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map).